# Google Sheets: Every time a cell changes I would like a new row in a database the the cell value + time stamp

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an Investment dashboard on Google Sheets that updates when i click a button.

I would like that each time the sheet is updated to create a new line in a Database to show my profit/loss over time.

for instance: A1 shows Profit/ Loss. B1 shows Profit/ Loss %
On update: A1 and B1's value should reflect in the next row on my database sheet ("Database") in the following format:
Coulomb A: Date & Time.
Coulomb B: A1 value
Coulomb C: B1 Value

Hope that makes sense. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no trigger that will respond to changes causes by scripts or formulas.  onEdit() responds to userEdits only.

Comment: the Triger for the sheet to update is a check box. so when i either check or uncheck that box the sheet updates. would that count as a user edit?

Answer (score 0):

Have your button script compare the sheet's current data to the new data and calculate the differences. Store this data into a 2D array, and have your script paste it onto a new row on your database sheet.

If this does not clarify the issue, please elaborate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To be honest, you are dealing with a complete beginner here. I was hoping for a snipit of code that I might adapt for my use. From my understanding, i think I need a for loop that will input a new line of data in a separate sheet each time the sheet is updated. and in addition create a time stamp for that update. Could you help me here?

Comment: To be quite honest about the matter a complete beginner will always remain a complete beginner if they don't begin to write their own code.